# How to clean up bunch of urls without having to write multiple str replace statements?

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace

Following are few example urls which need to be cleaned up:

- http://example.com//path/ Should become: http://example.com/path/
- http://example.com/path/?& Should become: http://example.com/path/
- http://example.com/path/?&param=one Should become:
- http://example.com/path/?param=one
- http://example.com///?& Should become: http://example.com/
- http://example.com/path/subpath///?param=one& Should become: http://example.com/path/subpath/?param=one

Without having to write `str_replace()` multiple times, is there a way to clean up the url?

Comment: Please submit what you've tried

Comment: Did not yet try, will submit as soon as I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sahil's method is horribly convoluted with 6 replacement elements, unnecessary character escaping in the pattern, and finite quantifiers on unwanted duplicated characters.  In fact, this simple url fails to be corrected: `http://example.com//path1`

Implement this much shorter, faster, cleaner, more readable method in your project instead:

Code ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6bd5ba14a84933d1e157dc0656247bf541cb290)):

```
$urls=array(
    "http://example.com//path/",
    "http://example.com/path/?&",
    "http://example.com/path/?&param=one",
    "http://example.com///?&",
    "http://example.com/path/subpath///?param=one&");
$urls=preg_replace(
    ['/(?<!:)\/{2,}/','/\?&/','/[?&]$/'],['/','?',''],$urls);
var_export($urls);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'http://example.com/path/',
  1 => 'http://example.com/path/',
  2 => 'http://example.com/path/?param=one',
  3 => 'http://example.com/',
  4 => 'http://example.com/path/subpath/?param=one',
)
```

Pattern explanations:

`/(?<!:)\/{2,}/` Match 2 or more slashes not preceded by a colon; replace with single slash.

`/\?&/` Match a question mark followed by an ampersand; replace with question mark.

`/[?&]$/` Match the last character if a question mark or ampersand; remove.

---

Also, here is my take on the url parsing approach:  ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd0ee27434cca2725d33536a18bece526fd7c943))

Code:

```
$urls=array(
    "http://example.com//path//to///dir////4/ok",
    "http://example.com/path/?&&",
    "http://example.com/path/?&param=one",
    "http://www.example.com///?&",
    "http://example.com/path/subpath///?param=one&");
foreach($urls as $url){
    $a=parse_url($url); 
    $clean_urls[]="{$a["scheme"]}://{$a["host"]}".  // no problems expected from these elements
        preg_replace('~/+~','/',$a["path"]).        // reduce multiple consecutive slashes to single slash
        (isset($a["query"]) && trim($a["query"],'&')!=''?'?'.trim($a["query"],'&'):'');  // handle querystring
}    
var_export($clean_urls);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'http://example.com/path/to/dir/4/ok',
  1 => 'http://example.com/path/',
  2 => 'http://example.com/path/?param=one',
  3 => 'http://www.example.com/',
  4 => 'http://example.com/path/subpath/?param=one',
)
```

Explanation of url component handling:

The `preg_replace()` pattern on the `path` element will match 1 or more slashes and replace them with a single slash.  This can also be achieved using `~/+(?=/)~` or `~(?<=/)/+~` and an empty replacement string, but the lookarounds are at least 2.5x slower than the no-look pattern.

The `query` handling line has an inline conditional that first checks if the `query` element exists, then...

If so, it will trim unlimited ampersands from both ends and check that the trimmed value is not empty.  Any qualifying strings will be trimmed of ampersands, and prepended with a question mark.

If not, an empty string is appended to the string to be pushed into `$clean_urls`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will be good for you:

```
<?php


// I merged your examples in this URL
$url= "http://example.com//path/?&param=value";
// Separate URL 
$parsed = parse_url($url);
// Path cleanup
$path = trim($parsed['path'],'/');
// Query string cleanup
$query = trim($parsed['query'],'&');
// Concatenate the URL parts 
echo sprintf("%s://%s/%s?%s",$parsed['scheme'],$parsed['host'],$path,$query);
```

Comment: I liked your approach, but if fails on `http://example.com//path1//path2/////?&param=value&` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29f3752109400997eedadf38bb05ad02137ceae6

Comment: Using a URL parser is definitely a superior approach. The implementation here is not perfect, but it's a good start to a robust implementation. +1